# DataTable can not pass parameters from Ajax to ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable, parameters

I have this problem when trying to pass a string parameter from DataTable with Ajax to an ASP.NET MVC controller: the parameter is not being sent.

I tried many forms of "data:" options. Please help me, I think I'm missing something important.

When (as a test) I initialize the parameter at the beginning of the controller with ttt="CO" everything goes fine!

```
$('#tblVacation').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": '/Vacation/LoadData2',
        "contentType": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "type": 'GET',
         "dataType": 'JSON',
         "data" : ' { ttt: "CO" }'
         "dataSrc": "",
    },
  
    "columns": [
        { "data": "vacationId", width: "5%" },
        { "data": "operatorId", width: "3%" },
        { "data": "operator", width: "10%" },
        { "data": "type", width: "3%" },
    ]
});
```

And the controller is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoadData2(string ttt)
    // ttt="CO";
{               
    List<Vacation> data = null;

    try
    {
        data = DB.Vacations.Include(x => x.Operator).ToList();

        var result = data.Select(x => new Vacation_VM
            {
                VacationId = x.VacationId,
                OperatorId = x.OperatorId,
                Vacation_doc = x.Vacation_doc,
                Operator = x.Operator.Name,
                Type = x.Type,                    
            }).Where(m => m.Type == ttt);

        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = ex.Message;
    }

    return new JsonResult(null);
}
```

I also tried with

```
var entity = {  
        ttt: "CO"     
    }
var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(entity);
```

and

```
 "data": function () {
                return dataToSend;
            },
```

but it's still not working. I will need in the future to pass multiple parameters.

Thanks a lot, I will appreciate any advice.

Comment: try to add it to url directly

Comment: You don't need to stringify your `entity`. Just use `var dataToSend = { ttt: "CO" };` and then use `"data": function () { return dataToSend; }`. Using the functional form of the `data` option is the correct approach. Because you are using `GET`, you will see `ttt=CO` added to the request URL as a query parameter.

Comment: If that does not work as expected then you can [edit] your question and provide a [mre]. Show us the code, provide some sample test data, and explain how you are triggering subsequent Ajax calls.

Comment: Finally it works with this form:  var dataToSend = { ttt: "CO" }; and then  "data": function () { return dataToSend; }.  Thanks a lot for helping me, I'm very happy after three days of searching!

Comment: To be clear, this approach (using the function) is needed if you want to send _different_ data to the server for each _new_ Ajax call, without needing to re-initialize the datatable. If you only want to send `ttt=CO` for _every_ Ajax call, then you can use the solution provided by @rahatur, or just hard-code the query parameter into the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ajax call part with the followings:

```
"ajax": {
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Vacation/LoadData2',
    data: { ttt: "CO" },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
},
```